# R or Excel: Determine daily max value of dissolved oxygen and get corresponding time in a dataframe

Tags: r, excel

I tried to code this on both R and excel, and can take any form of help. In excel I am able to look up the max value and report the time of day in the adjacent value by using this code.

```
 =(INDEX($D$1:$D$97,MATCH(MAX($E$1:$E$97),$E$1:$E$97,0)))
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to efficiently code this for my whole dataset without manually changing the formula for each row.

In R, I can't figure out how to return the adjacent cell value (ie, look up the max Dissolved oxygen and get back the corresponding time value). Here is what I have in R.

```
library(data.table)
df<- read.csv("Book3.csv")
df
setDT(df)
n <- 97
hi <- df[datetimes, max(DO), by= (seq(nrow(df)) - 1) %/% n]
```

any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Lauren Devito, Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you do ```dput(head(df))``` and add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Lauren in R the dplyr package would be very helpful here. What you want to do is something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv(filepath) %>%
filter(DO=max(.$DO) %>%
select(datetimes)
```

the `%>%` are called pipes and they basically pass the result from one function to the next. The `.$DO` is telling it to use the current data frame object and select the DO column. Then the select statement is telling it to only show you the datetimes column.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using data.table package, take advantage of the IDateTime class provided by it and simple subset by date. The only trick is to use `.SD` to show all the rows. Since you didn't provide a sample of your data, I'm generating an example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(222)
datetimes <- seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-03"), by = "3 hour")
exDT <- data.table(
  date = as.IDate(datetimes),
  time = as.ITime(datetimes),
  DO = rnorm(length(datetimes), 20, 5))

> exDT[, .SD[DO == max(DO)], by = date]
         date     time        DO
1: 2019-01-01 21:00:00 27.807025
2: 2019-01-02 06:00:00 25.262292
3: 2019-01-03 00:00:00  9.972435
```

Also check `?fread` to read your CSV file directly as a data.table.